# Adding buttons to the Windows 8 on-screen keyboard

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, on-screen-keyboard

The Microsoft 'stocks' app has a row of buttons that are displayed at the top of the keyboard when you search for stocks:

[image]

(See the buttons just above the keyboard)

Is there a way to add these in my own app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is exactly the same question [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/e665e515-406a-4b2c-be09-6e4a384fc570/) and a person from Microsoft answered:

> The keyboard is not extensible.  What you see is the bottom AppBar on
>   top of the keyboard in that situation.

I think you should subscribe to `Windows.UI.ViewManagement.InputPane.GetForCurrentView().Showing` event, to show that application bar with suggestions when screen keyboard is shown.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any idea whether there is a way of matching the keyboard colour scheme?