# Virtual Keyboard Customization

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, touch, multi-touch

Windows 7 and 8 have a virtual keyboard. (Actually, 2 of them, but I'm talking not about an 'On Screen Keyboard' from 'Ease of Access', but a virtual keyboard for Touch and Pen input devices). I've noticed that only Internet Explorer can customize it by changing or adding some buttons, like ".com", ".net" to speedup typing. Only when address box activated.

**I'm wonder weather I can add my own buttons for particular controls of my application (C#, WPF), e.g. 'Create New Item' or 'Link'.**

Please, do not suggest shortcuts, since it requires 2 buttons (I have kind of text box for typing by default and I cannot use single buttons as shortcut, and shortcuts much less obvious and easy-to-learn than a button clearly describing it function).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can not add buttons to the virtual keyboard. See [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/7349d01d-dc0e-4e1c-9327-df90e00fbebf/) MSDN social page and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13539277/adding-buttons-to-the-windows-8-on-screen-keyboard) SO post.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `TextBox.InputScope` property to enable the extra buttons.  You cannot make your own.